# How to consume and dismiss the PopupWindow when clicked outside?

Tags: android, dialog

I'm currently designing simple tips popups using the [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) class.  I'm able to dismiss the popup when clicked outside of the content. However the touch events outside are consumed by the underlining layout.  How can I consume the outside touches so that when clicked outside I still have the popup dismissed but there are no touch events being sent to the layout below my [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)?

***Current set properties:***

```
mPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.popup_bg));
mPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out there is a way to do it! After looking deep into PopupWindow and ListPopupWindow I discovered the option **setFocusable(true);** will do exactly what I needed!

Comment: Got to wait 2 days until I can :(

Answer (score 6):

If you are using ListPopupWindow then `setModal(true)` will do the trick.