# Issue dismissing popup window

Tags: android, popup

I have a popup menu implemented , which shows up on click of a button. This is my onclick method.

```
public void showOverflow(View view) {

    boolean click = true;
    Button action = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btbAction);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) main.this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overflow_layout, null);
    final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(popupView,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    if (click) {
        pw.showAsDropDown(action, 0, 0);
        click = false;
    } else {
        pw.dismiss();
        click = true;
    }
}
```

The popup window shows up when the button is clicked. Now, the problem is that the window is not dismissed when i touch outside the popup window. 
I tried setting this property to the popup window

```
pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

Things remain the same. Please help me fix this

Comment: Hi please check below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823606/how-to-consume-and-dismiss-the-popupwindow-when-clicked-outside

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change the `setOutsideTouchable` call's parameter to **`true`**:
`pw.setOutsideTouchable(false);`

> Controls whether the pop-up will be informed of touch events outside
>   of its window. This only makes sense for pop-ups that are touchable
>   but not focusable, which means touches outside of the window will be
>   delivered to the window behind. The default is **false**.
>
> If the popup is showing, calling this method will take effect only the
>   next time the popup is shown or through a manual call to one of the
>   update() methods.
>
> Parameters: `touchable` **true** if the popup should receive outside touch
>   events, **false** otherwise

On the other hand, what is the `click` local variable supposed to do? It is set to **true**, so it will always force the `pw` to pop up, whenever the `showOverflow` method is called, and for no reason it is set to **false** later, because it's life cycle ends as you leave that method.

Your code should look something like this:

```
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Button action;
private PopupWindow pw;
private View popupView;
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overflow_layout, null, false);

    action = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action);
    action.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void showOverflow()
{
    pw = new PopupWindow(getApplicationContext());
    pw.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pw.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);

    pw.setContentView(popupView);
    pw.showAsDropDown(action, 0, 0);
}
```

The `getApplicationContext()` shoud be used in case you are inside an `Activity` class. Otherwise you should get the `Context` as a parameter.

Comment: all I want is to dismiss the popup window (in poped up state) when i click outside the window, in the underlying activity. The local variable click is set to true when the popup is active. so when another click is performed, I check whether boolean click is false, so that i can dismiss the popup. Don't know whether I am doing it correctly.

Comment: tried pw.setOutsideTouchable(false);
the popup is not dismissed when I touch outside

Comment: please see my update for using the context in creating the `PopupWindow`. The `setOutsideTouchable` method can be modified, if you need your popup to be focusable / touchable. In this case you'll need a touch interceptor, to dismiss the popup when a `MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE` occurs.

Comment: and what does the LogCat say? Could you please paste the error's stack trace too?

Comment: Could you please paste the whole relevant output by editing your question? these lines do not help tracking the source of the exception.

Comment: I've edited the question. Please have a look at the error log

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11224/discussion-between-rekaszeru-and-stephensherbatsky)

Answer (score 0):

change `pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);` to `pw.setOutsideTouchable(false);`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but this is what I have done to fix it

The problem is:

> You are creating a new instance of popupwindow everytime you call showOverFlow() thats why after you close the popupwindow another popup window will show

What will you do is initialize popupview in `OnCreate`

Then call `popupwindow.showAsDropDown(view)` in `showOverFlow()` method

And lastly you can check whether is it showing below code

Put this code in your button onclick

```
  if(popupwindow.isShowing()){
  popup.dismiss() }
  else{
  ShowOverflow()}
```