# PopupWindow - Dismiss when clicked back but not outside

Tags: android, popupwindow

I want to clicked back button to dismiss PopupWindow.But I can also click outside to do another thing,the PopupWindow don't miss.
I try `popupWindow.setFocusable(true);`,but the PopupWindow will dismiss when I click outside.
I try to custom view.

```
public class OtherBrifeIntroView extends LinearLayout
{
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

}
```

but it doesn't work.Can you help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577596/issue-dismissing-popup-window, this will help.

Answer (score 3):

I solve it.Set `TouchModal` false,but the `setTouchModal` is hide,so I use reflect.

```
public static void setPopupWindowTouchModal(PopupWindow popupWindow, boolean touchModal)
    {
        if (null == popupWindow)
        {
            return;
        }
        Method method;
        try
        {
            method = PopupWindow.class.getDeclaredMethod("setTouchModal", boolean.class);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(popupWindow, touchModal);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Finally.

```
setPopupWindowTouchModal(popupWindow, false);
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: Answer of Egos Zhang absolutely right. I spent one day trying to solve this problem. I have checked this flag with 4.1 and 6 versions of os. --posted for @Michael Gayev

Answer (score 0):

You can call `popupWindow.dismiss()` to manually dismiss the `PopupWindow` within your `dispatchKeyEvent` method. In order to stop it dismissing when you touch outside of the `PopupWindow` there are a number of things you can try.

```
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popupWindow.setTouchable(true);
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
```

Have a play about with the above values and see what the outcome is, I am not on my developer computer at the moment so can't test which one it is.